# Integrating over a sphere of radius $r$

Tags: integration

> $$dA=r^2\,d\omega\hat r=(r^2\,d\mu \,d\varphi)\hat r$$$$d\omega=\sin\theta d\theta \, d\varphi$$ $$\mu=\cos\theta\Rightarrow\sin^2\theta=(1-\mu^2)$$$$d\mu=-\sin\theta \, d\theta$$

I don't understand the expression $dA$. How do I interpret it, how do I understand the equations, and how can I integrate over a sphere?

Answer (score 0):

$dA$ is an element of area on the surface of the object.  The object need not be a sphere.  $d\omega$ is an element of solid angle. The area it represents is $r^2 \, d\omega$.  Because we are talking about infinitesimal elements, the radius does not change enough to care about within the solid angle in question, so we consider it constant.  If your object is an ellipsoid or more complicated shape $r$ will vary over the surface, but in the neighborhood of any point it doesn't change enough to matter.  The expression is exact for a sphere because $r$ is truly constant.

Comment: Thank you and what is $\mu$ and $\varphi$ in expression of $d\omega$? And why is $d\omega $ exprssed that way?

Comment: $\mu$ and $\phi$ (I would use $\theta$ instead of $\mu$) are angular variables in spherical coordinates.  If you have some function that is being integrated over the surface, its values may be expressed in those terms so you can do the integral.

Comment: Thank you and where does $\sin \theta$ dissapear? I see $dA = r^2 \sin \theta d\varphi d\theta r_0$ but why is this equal to $r^2 d\mu d\varphi r_0$?

Comment: Why is this equal to $r^2 d\mu d\varphi r_0$ instead of $-r^2 d\mu d\varphi r_0$?

Comment: Now I see $\mu$ is $\cos \theta$, which is why the $\sin \theta$ term disappears.  What is $r_0$?  That hasn't been here before.  I suspect there is a lot more explanation in whatever text you are reading.

Comment: Sorry, $r_0$ is unit vector, wrong notation. The last I don't understand is the minus. $d\mu = -\sin \theta d\theta$ and after substituting into $dA$, why there is no minus?